# Spin up an Azure Container instance using the Fluent sdk, and a windows container

Tags: .net, azure, docker, .net-core, azure-container-instances

I'm trying to spin up an azure container instance using the azure container instance fluent management sdk. I'm using a windows based container. I get the following error:

System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: SpinUp. Microsoft.Azure.Management.ContainerInstance.Fluent: The OS version of image '/:v1' is not supported.

It works perfectly using a Linux based container - the code:

```
var credentials = new AzureCredentials(new ServicePrincipalLoginInformation
{
      ClientId = "myid",
      ClientSecret = "mysecret"
}, "mytenant", AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);

var azure = Azure
            .Configure()
            .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic)
            .Authenticate(credentials)
            .WithDefaultSubscription();
var group = azure.ContainerGroups.Define("testFloodscreener")
            .WithRegion(Region.USEast)
            .WithNewResourceGroup("UFHAEAST")
            .WithWindows()
            .WithPrivateImageRegistry("<myazurecr>", "<crusername>", "<crpassword>")
            .WithoutVolume()
            .DefineContainerInstance("<name>")
                .WithImage("<azurecr>/<imagename>:<tag>")
                .WithoutPorts()
                .WithCpuCoreCount(1)
                .WithCpuCoreCount(1)
                .WithMemorySizeInGB(1)
                .Attach()
            .WithRestartPolicy(ContainerGroupRestartPolicy.OnFailure)
            .Create();
```

Any help is appreciated - I can spin up the container instance manually

Answer (score 0):

So I found the answer myself, Azure Container Instances using windows based containers - does NOT support 1709 based images, according to this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-troubleshooting

Doh